# How to get the last record for column B and sum of column A in a group in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I apply the operation [nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) and `sum` in a single groupby operation on a dataframe? consider the following data -

```
   cust_id Qtr points_1   points_2
0   A      1    126.0095 126.009500
1   A      2    0.0000   126.009500
2   A      3    0.0000   126.009500
3   A      4    0.0000   126.009500
4   B      5    68.3600  131.364750
5   B      6    8.5751   139.939850
6   B      7    0.0000   139.939850
7   C      8    0.0000   139.939850
8   C      9    53.2800  123.249925
9   D      10   0.0000   123.249925
```

I can get the last element in a group using

```
df.groupby('cust_id')['points_2'].nth(-1)
```

But I want to generate the output like below where I get the sum of a column and the last element in the group of another. I tried using something like:

```
df.groupby('cust_id').agg({'points_1' : 'sum', 'points_2' : 'nth(-1)'})
```

but apparently, that's not the correct way I can specify the `nth` method.
What am I missing?

```
   points_1(SUM) points_2(last_in_the_group)
A  126.0095      126.0095
B  76.93         139.93
C  53.2800       123.2499
D  0.0000        123.2499
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) instead `nth`:

```
df = df.groupby('cust_id').agg({'points_1' : 'sum', 'points_2' : 'last'})
print (df)
         points_1    points_2
cust_id                      
A        126.0095  126.009500
B         76.9351  139.939850
C         53.2800  123.249925
D          0.0000  123.249925
```

Comment: Fascinating. I didn't realize 'last' exists. Is there an exhaustive list of all the functions supported by Pandas groupby? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader - yes, it exist - [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html)